# RoR-STimulus-Fetch-API : how to add something fetched to DB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fetch, stimulusjs

I am trying to add something I fetched from an API to my RoR DB.

So I have :

- my view :

  ```
  <div data-controller="album">

    <form data-album-target = "form"
       data-action="submit->album#update">
    <input  type="text"
          class="form-control"
          data-album-target="input">

    <div data-album-target="results"></div>

    </div>
  ```
- and my stimulus controller

  ```
    import { Controller } from "stimulus"

       export default class extends Controller {
      static targets = ["results", "input", "form"]

  update(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.resultsTarget.innerHTML = "";
    const artistName = this.inputTarget.value;
    const url = `https://theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/2/search.php?s=${artistName}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.findIdArtist(data);
      });
  }

  findIdArtist(data){
    data.artists.forEach((result) => {
      const idArtist = result.idArtist;
      const url2 = `https://theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/2/album.php?i=${idArtist}`;
      fetch(url2)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          data.album.sort(function (a, b) { return a.intYearReleased - b.intYearReleased }).forEach((list) => {
            const album =
              `<div class="card">
                <img src=${list.strAlbumThumb}>
                <div class="albumtitle">
                  ${list.strAlbum}
                </div>
                <div class="albumyear">
                  ${list.intYearReleased}
                </div>
              </div>`
            this.resultsTarget.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", album)
          })
        });
    });
  }
  }
  ```

How could I have a "+" button which adds the albumID to my RoR database ? I tried with a POST fetch but I can't get it to work.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Any error from your browser javascript console?

Comment: Hi Pedro, I just need a hint to how I can get it done. How would you do it ? 
Is the POST fetch a good idea ? Or is there a simplier way ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, you need a POST fetch and a controller method that receive the album information and save to your database. If you need more information from other API, is better to retrieve this in your controller too. You are welcome!!